# systemd service doesn't work anymore

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have an executable `secretserviced` which I want users be able to make a **user service** from it. I put this executable in `/usr/bin` and make a **Unit** file (`secretserviced.service`) as below and putting it at `/etc/systemd/user`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to keep secrets of applications
Documentation=https://github.com/yousefvand/secret-service

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RestartSec=30
Restart=always
Environment="MASTERPASSWORD=01234567890123456789012345678912"
WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/secretserviced
```

then a user can enable and start the service by: `systemctl enable --now --user secretserviced.service`

This method worked until few months ago but it no longer works.

What is wrong with my configurations?

**PS**: I use Archlinux

Comment: Try: `journalctl -u secretserviced.service` and scroll down to the end. You can also filter the log - for example: `--since today` etc.

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate answer, we'll need the output of the following:

```
systemctl status --user secretserviced.service
```

But here is my best guess based on the info provided.

---

`WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin/` is peculiar. If you need to specify a `WorkingDirectory=` it is usually either to define the root of a data-structure, or to define a place where your program will create output files. bin is not appropriate for either of those cases.  I suspect your is that your application is trying to write to `/usr/bin`, but your user does not have permission to do so.

In that case, try something like

- `WorkingDirectory=%h` to have it write to your home directory or
- `WorkingDirectory=%t` to have it write to a temporary runtime directory.
- `WorkingDirectory=%h/path/to/data` to have it use a specific data tree.

---

> "I put this executable in /usr/bin".

Generally, only `pacman` installs things to `/usr/bin`. Every file in there should return a package if you `pacman -Qo <filename>`. If you install things by manually copying or using `make install`, you should normally put them in `/usr/local/bin`. This makes it easy to see which files are managed by your distro, and which are managed by you.  The fact that you installed a file to `/usr/bin` yourself makes me think that there could be some problems with the installation.

Check that `/usr/bin/secretserviced` is spelled correctly and marked as executable.  If it's not executable, you can fix that with `sudo chmod w+x /usr/bin/secretserviced`.  If this is really the issue, then `systemd status --user secretserviced` will report `exit code 203`.

Comment: I forgot to `systemctl daemon-reload` but thanks for information

Comment: That'll do it too!